# Android Application - Временные зоны, часовые пояса: как это делается без "велосипеда"

Tags: java, android, время

Только приступил к программированию в своей жизни и уже куча преград с пониманием. А именно с проблемой синхронизации времени и даты на сервере (с которым происходит общение приложения) и локального времени и даты на самом устройстве с установленным приложением.
На данный момент разброс по времени может быть от часу до нескольких.
Теоретической информации море и всякой, но на погружение в тему кажется уйдет с месяц. У меня нет столько времени.
Возможно имеются какие-то стандартные простые решения?!
Суть в том, что независимо от того в каком часовом поясе находится смартфон с установленным приложением, отправляемые с него данные, содержащие дату и время, должны верным образом записываться на сервере в БД. И при обратной передаче с сервера такие данные как дата и время должны корректно отображаться в приложении на удаленном смартфоне.
Надеюсь я описал не сильно сложно, думаю опытные поняли в чем суть.
За любую помощь спасибо.
Язык: java
Среда: Android Studio

Comment: да зачем целый месяц разбираться? просто храните время **не в урезанном** виде, а в нормальном - вместе с часовым поясом.

Comment: Если хранить и обрабатывать время прошедших событий строго в UTC, то это решает все проблемы

Comment: Спасибо за наводку. Но не совсем понял механику реализации. К примеру сервер мобильного приложения расположен на камчатке. Смартфон с приложением физически находится в Англии. Получается при необходимости приложение должно на сервер передавать значение даты и времени в формате UTC?!

Comment: Ну да. Вы так пишете, как будто с таким подходом что-то не так, но все так и делают

Comment: не обязательно в формате UTC. приложение должно отдавать полное время ОБЯЗАТЕЛЬНО с указанием часового пояса. сервер сможет это сконвертировать и хранить в каком угодно (удобном для анализа) часовом поясе. и сервер отдает клиенту время с указанным часовым поясом. конечно, хороший тон если это будет UTC (со стороны сервера) , но это лишь "хороший тон" и не является обязательным условием. со стороны клиента подгонять время под нужный для сервера часовой пояс - плохое решение.

Comment: Благодарю, действительно прояснилось!